# GL_INVALID_OPERATION on glBufferData() in kotlin

Tags: opengl, kotlin, lwjgl

I am currently creating a game in Kotlin with OpenGL via LWJGL (for learning Kotlin). I created a class representing a VBO, which looks like this:

```
package de.pascal_riesinger.Testing.gfx

import de.pascal_riesinger.Testing.Log
import de.pascal_riesinger.Testing.LogLevel
import de.pascal_riesinger.Testing.logGLError
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15
import java.nio.FloatBuffer

class VBO() {

    private var id: Int = 0

    init {
        Log(LogLevel.DEBUG, "VBO", "Allocating new VBO")
        id = GL15.glGenBuffers()
        Log(LogLevel.DEBUG, "VBO", "Allocated VBO with id $id")
    }

    fun bufferData(data: FloatBuffer, usage: Int) {
        bind()
        GL15.glBufferData(id, data, usage)
        unbind()
    }

    fun bind() {
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id)
    }

    fun unbind() {
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
    }

}
```

Yes, I know that this code is not that beautiful, but I'm still very new to Kotlin's concepts.
Now when I run the following snippet:

```
  var vbo = VBO()
  var vertexBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(6)
  vertexBuffer.put(vertices)
  vertexBuffer.flip()

  //vbo.bind()
  vbo.bufferData(vertexBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW)
```

I will get an OpenGL error 1282, which is `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` right after the call to `glBufferData()`.

I googled for the error and per the OpenGL specification, `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is thrown by `glBufferData()` only in the following two cases:

> An INVALID_OPERATION error is generated by BufferData if zero is bound to target.
>
> An INVALID_OPERATION error is generated if the BUFFER_IMMUTABLE_STORAGE flag of the buffer object is TRUE.

The latter one **cannot** be the case, as my buffer is not immutable, and I verified that the generated ID of the buffer is not zero (it seems to always be one).

Note that uncommenting the `vbo.bind()` line does not fix this.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of [`GL15.glBufferData`](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL15.html#glBufferData) has to be a target (in your case `GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`), not the handle of the buffer.